# Android : Getting error when I setOnClickListener() for logoImage

Tags: java, android

I am getting error when i run this app on android :

Error :->>" Unfortunately exampleapp has stoped "

Please help me .. When I remove the line :

```
logoImage.setOnClickListener(this);
```

no problm , its working fine .. I think I made some mistake with setOnClickListener() .

thank you !

```
    package com.hightrax.mrgod;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener
    {

    ImageView logoImage;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        logoImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.logo);
        logoImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
logoImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.logo);
```

...should probably be this:

```
logoImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
```

...which also expects you to have an `<ImageView />` in your layout XML with the id `@+id/logo`, similar to this:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

If your `ImageView` isn't using the id `@+id/logo`, then just change the `R.id.logo` above to whatever you've picked. :-)

TLDR: You're trying to find a view based on the resource identifier of your `Drawable`. This is not the same as the identifier you've given your `ImageView`.

Answer (score 1):

`findViewById` must have a parameter that's a resource ID. You've added a drawable ID.

If your ImageView has the ID "imageView1" then you should do:
`logoImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);`

Comment: yes are correct .. when i change the  logoImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ID_NAME) its worked ... Thanks alot ...

Answer (score 0):

Change

`logoImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.logo);`

To

`logoImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);`